# Can't understand why I'm getting a `initialize': uninitialized constant Controller::View (NameError)

Tags: ruby, nameerror

I'm trying to understand why I'm getting this error and I suspect it's because I have my Controller class and View class in two separate Ruby files. I was told that using require_relative 'filename' should reference all the code from one file into another, but I seem to be missing something. Okay here goes,

In **controller.rb** file, I have

```
require_relative 'view'
require_relative 'deck_model'
require_relative 'flashcard_model'



class Controller

  def initialize
    @deckofcards = Deck.new
    @welcome = View.new.welcome
    @player_guess = View.new.get_user_guess
    @success_view = View.new.success
    @failure_view = View.new.failure
  end

  def run
    #Logic to run the game
    # @current_card
    # @user_guess
    puts "Let's see if this prints"
    # pull_card_from_deck

  end

end
```

In my **view.rb** file, I have,

```
require_relative 'controller'

class View

    attr_accessor :userguess

    def initialize (userguess = " ")
        @userguess = userguess
    end

    def welcome
        system ("clear")
        puts "Welcome! Let's play a game."
        puts "I'll give you a definition and you have to give me the term"
        puts "Ready..."
    end

    def get_user_guess
        @userguess = gets.chomp.downcase
    end

    def success
        puts "Excellent! You got it."
    end

    def failure
        puts "No, that's not quite right."      
    end


end
```

However when I run **controller.rb**, I get the following error,

```
/Users/sean/Projects/flash/source/controller.rb:11:in `initialize': uninitialized constant Controller::View (NameError)
from /Users/sean/Projects/flash/source/controller.rb:51:in `new'
from /Users/sean/Projects/flash/source/controller.rb:51:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/sean/Projects/flash/source/view.rb:1:in `require_relative'
from /Users/sean/Projects/flash/source/view.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from controller.rb:1:in `require_relative'
from controller.rb:1:in `<main>'
```

Can anyone please help me figure this out.

Comment: The backtrace you posted says the error is happening on line 51 of `/Users/sean/Projects/flash/source/controller.rb:51`, but the file you posted is a lot shorter.  Please post your whole code and the exact command you used to run it.

Comment: +1 to @DavidGrayson. I'd also remove `require_relative 'controller'` since your `View` class does not use any `Controller` code.

Answer (score 2):

You did not post your full code, but it sounds like this is an error caused by the circular dependencies you specified in your project.  You have `view.rb` depending on `controller.rb` and `controller.rb` depending on `view.rb`.  The Ruby interpreter will not execute these files simultaneously; it has to execute one and then execute the other.

It looks like it is executing `controller.rb` first, but it sees that `view.rb` is required, so it starts executing that.  Then in `view.rb` it sees that `controller.rb` is required, so it starts executing `controller.rb` again.  Then at some point in `controller.rb`, you must be creating a new instance of the `Controller` class.  But we aren't done defining the `View` class yet, so `View` is undefined and you get an exception while trying to create that controller.

To fix this, you should consider not creating any `Controller` or `View` objects until both of the classes are fully loaded.

Comment: Yes, that was it. Thank you so much David.

Answer (score 2):

+1 to @DavidGrayson comment.

If my assumption is correct, your issue is with `require_relative 'controller'` in your **view.rb** file.

If you see, it looks like `View` is requiring `Controller` then Controller gets loaded which seems to be sending `new` somewhere to `Controller` which then sends `new` to `View` but it hasn't been completely required.